# Fastest method for determining all substrings of existing string

Tags: php, string, algorithm, permutation, combinations

Let's say I have the string `"Hey"`. I would like to determine all combinations of characters that exist in this string as **fast** as possible. The resulting algorithm should generate this:

```
H, e, y, He, ey, Hey
```

The algorithm should *not* produce the string `"Hy"` because it *does not* exist in the string as a substring.

Comment: Why must it be fast? A trivial two-loops solution seems fast enough to me...

Comment: What is the answer for HeyHeyHey? Will it have 3 'Hey's or just one?

Comment: @wildplasser: What you propose seems like the fastest possible solution, from an algorithmic point of view.

Comment: So what have you tried? How much of an optimsation do you need? Do you need one at all? As fast as possible in what environment, some languages do strings better than others....

Comment: I know, but I didn't want to spoil his homework!

Comment: I would like to code it for php. I had considered the two loop method but I assumed that there may be a faster algorithm. The problem is that the strings may be long. I am very bad at theory like this but if you guys think its the fastest than I'll go with it. Thanks!

Comment: Well: there are two boundaries {begin,end} that have to be moved (almost) independently. This is one of these N * (N-1) things. There are a lot of them out there.

Comment: What do you want to do with the combinations afterwards?  Perhaps you can do better than O(n^2) if you only need a subset of them.  For example, if you just want to test membership of the resultant set that's easier.

Comment: The purpose of retrieving the subsets is to search for each one in a database. I realize that it may be faster to do the search the opposite direction (ie. get database results and find it in string) except the database will most likely be much larger than all the combinations of characters. Have not tested this theory though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are `O(n^2)` of those substrings, of lengths `[1,n]`, so any algorithm to generate **all of them** will be `O(n^2) * O(n) = O(n^3)`:

(*) See Edit2 at the end - depending on the implementation of the string - the complexity can vary from `O(n^2)` to `O(n^3)`

Pseudo code:

```
result <- {} #result is a set if dupes should be terminated, otherwise - it is a multiset.
for i from 0 to s.length:
   for j from i+1 to s.length:
      result.add(s.substring(i,j))
return result
```

Note however, that you can do some "cheating", by creating an iterator and generate the substrings on the fly, it should look something like this [pseudo code]:

```
class MyIterator:
  String s
  int i,j
  MyIterator(String s):
     this.s = s
     i = 0
     j = 0
  next():
     j = j + 1
     if (j >= s.length):
     i = i + 1
     j = i + 1
     if (i >= s.length): 
         throw exception
     return s.substring(i,j)
```

Note that creating the iterator is `O(1)`, and each iteration is `O(n)` - but to actually produce all the elements, you need `O(n^2)` steps, so complexity remains `O(n^3)` overall, but you decrease the latency of your application.

**EDIT:**

I editted complexity, claiming it is `O(n^2)` is wrong, the complexity is `O(n^3)` since you need to generate strings of variable lengths, some of them are long. At least half of the generated substrings will be of length `n/2` - thus the total complexity is `Theta(n^3)`

**EDIT2:**

In some cases it can actually be `O(n^2)` - depending on the string implementation. In java for example - it uses a single `char[]`, and only "plays" with the `offset` and `length` - so in java - creation is actually `O(n^2)`, since creating a substring is `O(1)`

In C however - it is `O(n^3)`, since every substring needs to be copied to a different `char[]`.

Comment: @TylerJohnson: I am not familiar with php I'm afraid, I do not know how a substring is created in php, but AFAIK most modern languages does not require copying the string, but it is only a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the implementation of n-grams in php.

In your example string: Hey

H, E, Y are unigrams

HE, EY are bigrams

HEY is a trigram

Comment: Maybe php has other meaning for n-grams, but [n-grams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) are *usually* refered to as terms/words. 1 word is unigram, 2 words is bigram, 3 words is trigram,... For example: [google n-grams](http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2006/08/all-our-n-gram-are-belong-to-you.html)

Comment: Hi Amit: NGrams may imply word or character. I dont code in PHP, I am taking in general. I use NGram Indexing in Lucene Search Engine for splitting the words. It can also be terms/words or characters.